# Is there way to check if an object exists and has a child in a single line?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to check if `req.user.premium` is true without having to check if `req.user` exists or is there a way to simplify this into a single line?

I've tried just checking `req.user.premium` but if `req.user` is empty then it throws an error because `req.user` is `undefined`, the same goes for `req.user && req.user.premium`.

```
if(req.user){
    if(req.user.premium){
        console.log('Is premium');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `req.user.premium`? please add detail code.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I could add. It states in the first line "Is there a way to check if req.user.premium is true".

Comment: You seem to be mistaken. `if (req.user && req.user.premium)` WILL NOT throw if req.user is undefined. In JS (and every other language I know), given `if (x && anything)`, if `x` evaluates false, the other conditions are not evaluated, so they cannot throw even if they otherwise would.`if (false && 3/0 === 5)` <== will not throw

Comment: and yet it is.. ? I was expecting the same thing but I'm getting an undefined error. Granted this is on node but there shouldn't be any difference between that and "vanilla" js.

Comment: Perhaps `req` is what's undefined?

Comment: Please note the [Mozilla docs for Logical Operators in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) explain that `if` and similar evaluations of conditionals use short circuiting.  Particularly, note:  "`false && (anything)` is short-circuit evaluated to false"

Comment: In general, If only evaulates to true if the value is not falsy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) & it evaluates in the order of expression so if the first value if falsy, later two will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line, (assuming you still console.log an empty val):

```
console.log((req.user && req.user.premium) ? 'Is premium' : '');
```

OR 2 lines (1 statement line):

```
if(req.user && req.user.premium)
    console.log("is premium");
```

**EDIT:**

Assuming your req object is undefined... do this:

One line, (assuming you still console.log an empty val):

```
console.log((req && req.user && req.user.premium) ? 'Is premium' : '');
```

OR 2 lines (1 statement line):

```
if(req && req.user && req.user.premium)
    console.log("is premium");
```

If the first condition (req) is undefined, the second and third conditions will not be evaluated - AKA: [Short-Circutiing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation))

Comment: If you read the question you'd see that I stated that causes an issue because if `req.user` is not set then `req.user.ANYTHING` would be `undefined`.

Comment: This uses short circuiting, so you won't encounter req.user being undefined on second condition

Comment: This returns `undefined`.

Comment: Turns out the line was undefined because of a line below what I was expecting. Since this changed the 2 lines to 1 line the line below it was showing the error.

Comment: Glad you fixed the issue, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(req.user && req.user.premium){
     console.log('Is premium');
}
```

that's about as simple as it gets

you can also do:

```
var premium = false;

try{
  premium = req.user.premium;
}
catch(err){

}
```

Comment: If you read the question you'd see that I stated that causes an issue because if `req.user` is not set then `req.user.ANYTHING` would be `undefined`.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find a way around.. That's why I asked this question. I also don't want to have to wrap lines after lines in try catch statements. I'm after an alternative to this.

Comment: If `req.user` is not set, the second part of the if statement should not even be considered, and there should not be a problem with undefined ...